# Bootstrap dividir as células com mesmo espaçamento

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Boa noite, estou tentando fazer uma table em bootstrap com 7 colunas, porem preciso que elas tenham o mesmo espaçamento.. estou utilizando  porque com a estrutura dos col-md, sm, xl... não deu por 7 se tratar de um numero primo, então quando utilizo as  responsiva, as células também ficam , e se eu estipular um width elas não diminuem, e em % nao fica exato.. alguma ideia?

```css
.eventodia{
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: solid 1px;
 height: 120px;
 width: 13%;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0px">
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Domingo</th>
    <th>Segunda</th>
    <th>Terça</th>
    <th>Quarta</th>
    <th>Quinta</th>
    <th>Sexta</th>
    <th>Sábado</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>daadsasdasdd</td>
    <td>dasd</td>
    <td>dasd</td>
    <td>dasd</td>
    <td>dasd</td>
    <td>dasd</td>
    <td>dasd</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: coloca <td nowrap="true"> que então o conteúdo da tabela vai dar quebra automática e o espaçamento vai ficar normal.

Comment: Você pode customizar seu bootstrap e baixar ele da forma que quiser pelo
Site do bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ No seu caso é só ir na parte de Grid System e alterar o @grid-columns para 7 ou múltiplo